# Windows 2003 R2, msiexec with /qn option failes to install

Tags: installation, windows-server-2003, setup, windows-installer

Hi I am running typical issue on msiexec, when i try to install a .msi component with /qn option it is not installing ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very late answer so you probably no longer care, but if you do, I would suggest running a log with `msiexec /l*v` or even `/l*vx` and seeing what is in there.  Generally the log gives at least a hint.